# Segmentation fault in Pandas with groupby

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, segmentation-fault

I'm computing features with a `groupby` statement in Pandas and I keep getting segmentation faults. The dataframe `df` has shape roughly `(10**7, 2)`

```
for value in value_list:
  df_tmp = df[df["feature"]==value]
  df_tmp.groupby("user_id", as_index=False).count()["feature"]
```

> Segmentation fault: 11

and sometimes

> Bus error: 10

Does anyone have an idea of how I can solve this?

I'm using Pandas 0.17.1, Numpy 1.10.4 with Anaconda on OSX 10.11.1.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: question why don't you just do `some_dataframe.groupby("user_id", as_index=False)["some_feature"].count()`? not that this solves your issue but you're aggregating all columns when you only care about 1

Comment: You're right thanks, I didn't even think I was wasting memory. This doesn't solve the problem I'm having though...

Comment: Could you provide a minimal test case that triggers it?

Comment: I'm trying to generate a minimal one, the data frame I'm handling has ~10^7 rows

Comment: @EdChum Actually the dataframe has only 2 columns, so I think this is equivalent.

Comment: Not sure if anyone is ever checking this: But was your seg fault intermittent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone interested, I managed to solve this. The problem came from `NaN` values in the column `user_id`...

Once I got rid of these, the `groupby` statement worked without any problem.

Comment: I think I had a mixed column of numbers and string, but that's probably the same underlying issue - two different types in a single column.